# Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name error- Needle Post Request to Google PubSub API

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, needle.js

I am using the following code to do a Post request to Google PubSub API:

```
  pushMessages = async function()
    {
      //const collection = context.services.get(`mongodb-atlas`).db(`billing`).collection(`projectdata`);
      var needle = require('needle');
      
       
    var postData = {
        "message": "hello world"
    }
      
      
     needle
      .post('https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/topicname:publish', postData, { json: true },  
      function(err, resp) {
      if (err)
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err.message));
      else
        console.log('OK.'+ JSON.stringify(resp.body));
      });
}
```

and I keep getting:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"message\": Cannot find field.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest","fieldViolations":[{"description":"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"message\": Cannot find field."}]}]}}.
```

Any hint on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `base64-encoded string` to publish into google pub/sub as show on the documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage). So, not just making the data into a `json` will work, you also need to encode it.

Please take as reference the node.js client libraries for [cloud pub/sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#publish_messages).

```
const data = JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'});
const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);
const messageId = await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer);
...
```

Also you can check the API `rest/v1/projects.topics/publish` details on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish).

Comment: Hello @OuterSpace, did you find this resourceful?